# Convergence of the series $ \sum\limits_n\int_{0}^{1/n}(\sinh(x))^{3/2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the series:$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{1/n}(\sinh(x))^{3/2}dx$$ converge or diverge?

I intend to find $k$ such that $\sinh(x)\leq kx$ for all $x$ in $[0;\frac{1}{n}]$ but I can't find it. Could someone give me a hint to solve this problem?

Comment: Good approach. Try $k=\sinh 1<1.2$.

Comment: for big enough $n$ you can replace $\sinh(x)$ by $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ 0\leq\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\sinh(x)^{3/2}\,dx \leq \sqrt{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}x^{3/2}\,dx\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(\frac{\sinh(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^3\,dx}\tag{1}$$
but over the interval $[0,1]$ the convexity of the $\sinh$ function grants $\sinh(x)\leq\sinh(1)x$, hence:
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\sinh(x)^{3/2}\,dx \leq \sinh(1)^{3/2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}x^{3/2}\,dx = \frac{2\sinh(1)^{3/2}}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}\tag{2}$$
and:
$$ 0\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}\sinh(x)^{3/2}\,dx \leq \color{red}{\frac{2}{5}\,\zeta\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\sinh(1)^{3/2}}\approx 0.68362.\tag{3}$$
An even tighter inequality can be deduced from 
$$\forall x\in(0,1),\qquad \sinh(x) < x\left[1+(\sinh(1)-1)\,x^2\right].\tag{4}$$

Comment: Jack, I hope all is well. +1 for this answer, but curious as to the reason for referencing the CS inequality.

Comment: @Dr.MV: it is not really exploited in $(2)$, but if one is able to produce tight approximations for the integral of $\frac{\sinh(x)^3}{x^{3/2}}$ may also improve $(3)$ and the approximation given by $(4)$, that is the reason.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: I can't prove (4) . Could you give me some hints?

Comment: @PhuongVu: prove that $\frac{\sinh\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a convex function in a right neighbourhood of the origin (that is trivial if you consider the Taylor series centered at the origin of such entire function).

Comment: For the downvoter: please explain your downvote.

Comment: ridiculous downvote removed (+1)

Answer (score 3):

For $n\geq 2$, you have that $0\leq \sinh(x)^{3/2}\leq \sqrt x$.
Then,
$$\int_0^{1/n}\sinh(x)^{3/2}\mathrm d x\leq \int_0^{1/n}\sqrt{x}\mathrm d x=\frac23\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$

Since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}<+\infty ,$$
the claim follow.